# How can i make sure installed packages get to team members through TFS?

Tags: .net, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

On my dev team we have had a few issues with Nuget packages not getting through TFS to team members. Is there anyway to guarantee this?

Comment: Are those packages checked-in into TFS Source Control, or are you making use of NuGet's Package Restore feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xavier mentioned, you should enable the "package restore" feature on your solution. See [Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) for details.